# Remove code lines on release version using gradle in Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have build a SDK JAR project with a Logger class which notify about system logs.
for example:

> Logger.log("error on line 123 please check", Logger.SDK_DEBUG);

At the moment there are few log levels that i can use.

I would on release build to remove all log messages that are with Logger.SDK_DEBUG in my code before the JAR build proccess. is it possible doing that with Gradle?

Comment: @user1096901- Yes, I will write the answer as a new comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a gradle script which handle the deletion of all Logger lines in the project. You will want to run this before any Gradle build command.

```
task deleteJavaDebugLogs << {
    description("This function will delete all SDK DEBUG log level from the project, be careful with it!")
    //Put your project full path for exmple 'src/main/java/myproject' , the path must be with quotes
    FileTree  javaFiles = fileTree('[your_project_path]') {
        // if you have more files that are not .java include them also.
        include '**/*.java'
    }
    String regex = "Logger.log[^,]+[^L]+(.*)Logger.SDK_DEBUG[^;];"
    javaFiles.each { File javaFile ->
        println "Start replacing regex on $javaFile.name"
        String content = javaFile.getText()
        content = content.replaceAll(regex, "")
        javaFile.setText(content)
    }
}
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it but from the definithion of code obfuscator, it should do this for you. Since it should find all unreachable code and remove it. If the Logger.SDK_DEBUG is final, he should know it is unreachable right?

Comment: The script i wrote would delete all Logger.SDK_DEBUG lines inside your android studio active project. Afterwards you have to compile and build in order to release it.
I haven't tried it on obfuscated code since I wanted to delete and later verify that the project is still compiled. 

I'm performing it as a step in Jenkins, if for some reason the project the will not be complied, I'll be notified on the compile step.

When I investigated this issue, I found that proguard can delete log lines
as well, but I felt much safer with the gradle script.

Comment: Well point is that you should always obfuscate release version of the android app and logger code lines are unreachable which should be removed in the obfuscation process automatically. Btw, Safer? In the worst case you will end up with few lines of unreachable code with logs making the .apk file larger at maximum. But I dont see any risk in that.